# Popover size couldn't be changed and looks with wrong height

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am working with `iPad` Application. I am trying to show the `UIPopOverController` from clicking the button. But when I do that with my following code, **It looks with wrong height of the pop over.**

Here it is my code.

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 500);
SignatureViewController *signatureViewController = [[SignatureViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SignatureViewController" bundle:nil];
signatureViewController.delegate = self;
signatureViewController.title = @"Draw Signature";

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:signatureViewController];

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
[signatureViewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButton];

[popover presentPopoverFromRect:signatureImageView.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
self.popOverController = popover;
```

My popover looks like this.

[image]

Its also showing on the navigation bar. What I am doing wrong in my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you could check here:

- `self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 500);` should really be inside your `signatureViewController` definition (viewDidLoad for example)
- Try changing `UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown` to `UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny`. There might just not be enough space to display that popover given the location and arrow pointing down requirements